# How to set ion-select-option checked based on specific key in data object?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm using Ionic v4. How do I check ion-select-option based on a key`IsSelected==true` in `users` object?

```
users = [{text:"Piet",IsSelected:false},{text:"Koos",IsSelected:true}];
```

```
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="users" [compareWith]="compareWith">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let usr of users">{{usr.text}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

Is it possible to do it with `compareWith`?

```
    compareWith = (user1, o2) => {
        //How do I check IsSelected here?
        return o1.IsSelected;
      };
```

Thanks

Comment: comparewith is used to compare the objects. I believe it is not something you wanted though?

Comment: I want to 'check' all the ion-select-option items which IsSelected == true.. I don't know how this can be accomplished, and if compareWith should be used

Answer (score 0):

can you try like the below solution:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Employee</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="employee" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee"></ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

compareFn(e1: Employee, e2: Employee): boolean {
  return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2;
}
```

instead of id you could use `isSelected`

Comment: Unfortunately not working. As a side note : return e1 && e2 ? e1.id === e2.id : e1 === e2; selects the first item

Comment: ok. then can you try `ngIf` and inside that a selected query. ngIf will check whether isSelected is true. Also i think your select needs multiple to be true like multiple=true

Answer (score 0):

To select/check the ion-select-option items in the data array based on key `IsSelected==true`

**Array**

```
users = [{text:"Piet",IsSelected:false},{text:"Koos",IsSelected:true}];
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="users" [compareWith]="compareWith" >
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let usr of users" [value]="usr" >{{usr.text}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

`[value]="usr"` is necessary for `compareWith` function

```
  compareWith = (o1, o2) => {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.text === o2.text && o1.IsSelected  : o1 === o2;
  };
```